# Magento 2 - Delete Single page cache

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache

If I go to `System->Tools->Cache Management`, flush page cache then it will flush all the pages cache. I need to figure out the way to flush single page specifically which I want.

Any help, experience and knowledge sharing would be appreciated.